# Gostaria que uma TextView exibisse a quantidade de CheckBoxes que foram marcadas

Tags: android, checkbox

Fiz várias tentativas, porém não obtive sucesso, eis o código da MainActivity.java:

```js
package genesysgeneration.cbnumber;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox cb_01, cb_02, cb_03, cb_04, cb_05, cb_06, cb_07, cb_08;
    int cont = 0;
    TextView tvContador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cb_01=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb_02=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        cb_03=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        cb_04=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        cb_05=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        cb_06=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
        cb_07=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
        cb_08=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);

        tvContador=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContador);
        tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont));

    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked (View view){

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.checkBox1:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox2:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox3:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox4:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox5:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox6:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox7:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

            case R.id.checkBox8:
                if(checked)
                    cont+=1;
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

O que acontece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o que eu gostaria que acontecesse exatamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, deixa eu dar uma dica, você pode tentar simplificar esse código. 
Já que todos são checkbox e são basicamente a mesma view. Tente fazer um método só que vai contar e atualizar o TextView, e chame ele nos checkbox. Isso vai reduzir seu código e vai facilitar as futuras correções e melhorias. 
Tente fazer isso:

```
public class Teste extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    CheckBox cb_01, cb_02, cb_03, cb_04, cb_05, cb_06, cb_07, cb_08;
    int cont = 0;
    TextView tvContador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste);

        cb_01=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb_02=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        cb_03=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        cb_04=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        cb_05=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        cb_06=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
        cb_07=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
        cb_08=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);
        tvContador=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContador);

        cb_01.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_02.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_03.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_04.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_05.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_06.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_07.setOnClickListener(this);
        cb_08.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {

            cont += 1;
            tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

        } else {

            cont -= 1;
            tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se a referência a cada um dos CheckBox só é necessária para atribuir o *listener*, pode simplificar o código atribuindo o *listener* no *xml*.

activity_main.xml

```
...
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" 
    ...
    android:onClick="onCheckBoxClick"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2" 
    ...
    android:onClick="onCheckBoxClick"/>

...
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    int cont = 0;
    TextView tvContador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onCheckBoxClick(View view) {
        if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
            cont++;
            tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));
       else{
            cont--;
            tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Costumo fazer assim mas quis ser mais convencional hoje kkk

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost As duas são válidas. A resposta que tinha preparado tinha as duas possibilidades, como você respondeu com uma coloquei apenas esta.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui a solução pouco depois da pergunta, porém olhei e vi que ninguém ainda a havia respondido. Decidi eu mesmo mostrar como resolvi.

Segue o código:

```js
package genesysgeneration.cbnumber;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox cb_01, cb_02, cb_03, cb_04, cb_05, cb_06, cb_07, cb_08;
    int cont = 0;
    TextView tvContador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cb_01=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb_02=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        cb_03=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        cb_04=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        cb_05=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        cb_06=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
        cb_07=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
        cb_08=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);
        tvContador=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContador);

        addCheck();

    }

    private void addCheck() {

        cb_01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {

                    cont += 1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                } else {

                    cont -= 1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_04.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_05.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_06.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_07.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

        cb_08.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){

                    cont+=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }else {

                    cont-=1;
                    tvContador.setText(String.valueOf(cont + " de 8 foram marcados."));

                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Amigo, deixa eu dar uma dica, voce pode tentar simplificar esse código. Já que todos são checkbox e são basicamente a mesma view. Tente fazer um método só que vai contar e atualizar o TextView, e chame ele nos checkbox. Isso vai reduzir seu código e vai facilitar as futuras correções e melhorias.